# compiling *.h files in objective c Linux

Tags: objective-c, linux

Im learning objective C (using a mac in my work)
In  my house I only have a Linux box, I'm using it to compile the objective c,
so far its been a good path, but now, I got to the stage of using the interface  *.h file in a different file than the *.m,
I was using

```
gcc `gnustep-config --objc-flags` -lgnustep-base 6_header.m -o 6_header
```

to compile  the programs for testing,
but it doesnt work it a separate .h file,
what to add? or change?

thank you!

Comment: .h files are never compiled...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your .h file should get included correctly from the .m. Just make sure the .m has `#import "some_file.h"`.

Also, just like in regular C, the .h should be in the same directory. If not, you can pass `-I/some/other/path` to look for .h's inside `/some/other/path`

Comment: np :) I see you're new to SO. Once an answer solves your problem, please pick it as the solution (via the green checkbox).